# Ошибка компилятора Visual Studio при объявлении заголовочных файлов

Tags: c, компиляция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]После объявления файла "header.h" просит поставить ;(см. список ошибок на картинке). Для системных файлов такого не происходит.

Comment: Укажите ошибку текстом. Другие люди, которые будут пытаться справиться с такой же ошибкой не смогут найти этот вопрос по картинке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка не у компилятора :)

```
#include "header.h"
```

вносит в ваш файл содержимое `"header.h"` как оно есть, т.е. вы получаете

```
void linear(void) 
int main (void) { 
....
```

Вы все еще не видите ошибку?

После

```
void linear(void)
```

нет запятой! у вас получилось

```
void linear(void) int main (void) { 
....
```